# DB2 Select Query for CLOB data not working via Linux

Tags: sql, linux, db2, clob

I am trying to search a complex string from CLOB data in DB2.
My Search String is - "salary":"10000"

And my query is below -

### *Select * From Employee where dbms_lob.instr(PRINT_DATA,  '"salary":"10000"')*

where PRINT_DATA is a CLOB column in Employee table.

when i run this query on DB2 Visualizer tool, it is giving me correct records with data.
But when i run the same query via Linux on my DB server , it is returning 0 records.
Does anyone has any idea of this different behaviour from Linux machine ?

I tried to use the escape character as well ("salary"\:"10000") but no luck.
It is very strange that same query is working on DB2 Visualizer tool but not working when i am executing this on Linux machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use correct escaping.
Your shell "eats" double quotes otherwise.

Shell tests:

```
# No double quotes in the constant!
$ echo db2 "select print_data::varchar(80) from employee_my where dbms_lob.instr(print_data, '"salary":"10000"')"
db2 select print_data::varchar(80) from employee_my where dbms_lob.instr(print_data, 'salary:10000')

$ echo db2 "select print_data::varchar(80) from employee_my where dbms_lob.instr(print_data, '\"salary\":\"10000\"')"
db2 select print_data::varchar(80) from employee_my where dbms_lob.instr(print_data, '"salary":"10000"')
```

Db2 tests:

```
db2 "create table employee (print_data clob (100k))"
db2 "insert into employee_my (print_data) values ('abc \"salary\":\"10000\" xyz')"

db2 "select print_data::varchar(80) from employee_my"
1
------------------------
abc "salary":"10000" xyz

# Correct escaping == correct result
db2 "select print_data::varchar(80) from employee_my where dbms_lob.instr(print_data, '\"salary\":\"10000\"')"

1
------------------------
abc "salary":"10000" xyz

# No escaping == wrong result
db2 "select print_data::varchar(80) from employee_my where dbms_lob.instr(print_data, '"salary":"10000"')"

1
-----------------------

  0 record(s) selected.

# Wrong escaping == wrong result
db2 "select print_data::varchar(80) from employee_my where dbms_lob.instr(print_data, '"salary"\:"10000"')"

1
-----------------------

  0 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Thanks @mark-barinstein. It is working now. I was using the escape character in a wrong way